# Autoadapt the size of a container

Tags: flutter

I'm looking to use a container but I have to auto adapt him height in terms of him child.
My part of code is the next :

```
return Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                            border: Border.all(color: kColorPurple, width: 1)),
                          height: 50,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: kColorPurple,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                ),
                                child: const Icon(
                                  Icons.title_rounded,
                                  size: 30,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                height: 60,
                                width: 230,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    const Text('Titre du projet :',
                                      style:
                                        TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                      child: Text(data['tricotTitle'],
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  )
                ]
              ),
```

In my screen I got this result :

[Part of the screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxJKr.jpg)

So I want to have the height of the container with an auto adaptation that's keep my actual font size.

Any one have a solution ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use **"overflow"** Text option

```
Text(
  'Text largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
```

Comment: That's a quite good idea but that's hide the text and I want to adjust the container's height

Comment: try to wrap the container you want to adapt with Expanded()